# conditional exports and bundle size inconsistencies when using turborepo monorepo with next.js app and buildable package

Tags: webpack, next.js, monorepo, esbuild, turborepo

Just trying to scaffold a JS/TS monorepo using Turborepo:

```
.
└── root
    ├── apps
    │   ├── first-app (next.js app)
    │   └── second-app (next.js app)
    ├── configs (ts, tsup)
    └── packages
        └── ui (react lib)
```

The public repo for reproduction can be found [here](https://github.com/hubertkuoch/next-monorepo). The two issues I have are the following:

###### 1. Next.js app does not seem to recognize conditional exports `mjs/cjs` extensions from buildable package

###### Reproduction

```
# second-app build will fail
pnpm build second-app...
```

###### Expected behaviour

Next.js app should be able to resolve `mjs/cjs` conditional exports

###### Current workaround

Current hack consists in using `js` extension for buildable package artifacts:

```
// ./configs/tsup.config.base.ts

// REPLACE THIS:
  outExtension({ format }) {
    return {
      js: `.${format === "esm" ? "mjs" : "cjs"}` // UNCLEAR WHY THIS DOES NOT WORK???
    }
  }

// BY THAT:
  outExtension({ format }) {
    return {
      js: `.${format === "esm" ? "esm.js" : "cjs.js"}` // THIS WORKS
    }
  }
```

```json
// `./packages/ui/package.json`

// REPLACE THIS:
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./.build/index.mjs",
      "require": "./.build/index.cjs"
    }
  },

// BY THAT:
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./.build/index.esm.js",
      "require": "./.build/index.cjs.js"
    }
  },
```

###### 2. Inconsistent bundle size

###### Reproduction

```
# Make sure the changes above are made for builds to work

# This shows 92kb first load JS
pnpm build --filter first-app

# This shows 143kb first load JS ?!
pnpm build --filter second-app...
```

###### Expected behaviour

`first-app` and `second-app` are the same simple app based on [Next.js/MUI template](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs-with-typescript), the only difference being that `second-app` imports some MUI/emotion related code of the template from the `ui` buildable package (instead of direct dependencies).

I expected the two app first load JS to be close but it shows nearly c.50kb difference.

###### Current workaround

None, currently out of idea to solve this properly given my limited experience with bundlers in general.

Thanks much for your help,

Answer (score 0):

try add this on package.json on the buildable package

```
"sideEffects": false,
```

Reading:

- https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69866774/7674911